# $.getJSON is not pulling updated information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am building a web site where I pull and push json files containing information. I know I should be using a database in the interest of speed, but I don't have the knowledge to do that yet. Anyway, every second the page will pull a new JSON file with a JQuery.getJSON call and append it to an element, like so:

```
function update(){
    $.getJSON(path, function(data){
        $("#entryContainer").empty().append(data.entry); 
    });
    window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
```

I use an ajax call to a PHP script to write over the old json with the same path. The PHP executes correctly :

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $path = $_POST['path'];

    $file = fopen($path, 'w+');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Most of the time this setup works perfectly. Though the first time I try to push an update to the json, the $.getJSON does not actually pull an updated file. After I refresh the page, the update will show and the $.getJSON will actually be responsive.

Why does this happen? Is the json being cached? Reloading the page on a successful execution is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried disabling the cache: `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`

Answer (score 0):

By default getJSON caches in jQuery. You really should set no cache headers on the serverside and/or make the Ajax call without the helper method.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: path,
    cache: false,  //do not cache
    success: function(data){
        $("#entryContainer").empty().append(data.entry); 
    }
});
```